php_curl.ddl not found using EasyPHP devserver 17, PHP 8.3.3
My php.ini contains:
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php833vs16x86x240904030356\ext"

php_curl.dll is in that directory.
The error.log contains:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\\eds-binaries\\php\\php833vs16x86x240904030356\\ext\\curl (The specified module could not be found), C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\\eds-binaries\\php\\php833vs16x86x240904030356\\ext\\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\\eds-binaries\\php\\php833vs16x86x240904030356\\ext\\openssl (The specified module could not be found), C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\\eds-binaries\\php\\php833vs16x86x240904030356\\ext\\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

The actual error.log file's text uses double backslash but I see that the text above shows single backslash.
I tried changing the extension_dir but when I restart the server, the php.ini line extension_dir is actually changed back to the same original value no matter what I change it to.

I get a more specific error message dialog box:
The procedure entry point
nghttp2_option_set_no_rfc9113_leading_and_traling_ws_validation could not be located in the dynamic link library
[followed by the php_curl.dll location]
